# AG-GRID: add column menu to a column group

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

I am building an application and I need to add the [Column Menu](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-menu/) to a [Column Group](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-groups/)

[image]

I need to show/hide a column group and I need the column management feature:

[image]

I need to enable the menu for a column group:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: I have the same question. Apparently it's impossible out-of-box, you will need to implement a [custom header component](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/component-header/#example-custom-header-component) and include the column menu component there.